# jQuery, Firebase,how to reach a variable inside a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am really confused on how to handle this variables, all I want to do is a little if comparation between **nombre** y **estado**, but both variables are product of a promises and I'll be really grateful if you could help me or guide in some way.

```js
  verificaUsuario() {
    var nombre1 ;
    let nombre4=this.storage.get('UID').then((value) => {
      var ref = firebase.database().ref("usuarios/" + value);
      let nombre3 = ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        var nombre2 = snapshot.child("nombre").val();
        return nombre2;
      });
    });

    console.log(nombre4 + "fuera");

    let estado = jQuery.get('http://172.31.45.34/nombres.txt', function (estado) {
      estado = estado.split(/\n/ig);
      estado.pop();
      console.log(estado);
      return estado;
    });
    console.log(estado);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < estado.length; i++) {
      if (estado[i] == nombre4) {
        console.log("usuario registrado");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have 2 promises and you want to compare results from both

You may want to use [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to combine promises

```
verificaUsuario() {
    var nombre1 ;
    let nombre4=this.storage.get('UID').then((value) => {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("usuarios/" + value);
        let nombre3 = ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        var nombre2 = snapshot.child("nombre").val();
        return nombre2;
        });
    });

    console.log(nombre4 + "fuera");

    let estado = jQuery.get('http://172.31.45.34/nombres.txt', function (estado) {
        estado = estado.split(/\n/ig);
        estado.pop();
        console.log(estado);
        return estado;
    });
    console.log(estado);

    jQuery.when(nombre4, estado).then(function (nombre4Result, estadoResult) {
        for (var i = 0; i < estadoResult.length; i++) {
            if (estadoResult[i] == nombre4Result) {
                console.log("usuario registrado");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, and what would it be, if I get [object Object] after return estado outside of the jquery

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, can you please explain?